# Passing a const pointer argument to a member function of a template class

Tags: c++, templates

Consider the following class:

```cpp
template<typename T> class A{
public:
    virtual void foo(const T& v){ m_v = v + 1; }    
    T& bar(){ return m_v;}
    T m_v;
    // ... other member functions/variables ...
};
```

How can it be modified such that the following code works (without, if possible having to to a `const_cast` on `p`):

```cpp
int main(){
    A<int*> a;
    const int* p = nullptr;
    a.foo(p);
    a.bar();

    A<int>().foo(10);
}
```

The problem is that the signature of the `foo` method, when `A` is templated by `int*` becomes, as far as I can tell, `foo(int* const&)`. What we would like to have would be something like `foo(const int* const&)`.

Until now, I considered adding a specialized implementation of the `foo` member function for `A` templated by pointer types outside the class declaration (as one would do for specializing `A<int>::foo`), but the compiler is not able to resolve the function definition prototype to the declared method.

```cpp
template<typename T>
void A<T*>::foo(const T* const& ){}
```

gcc complains that it's an `invalid use of incomplete type ‘class A<T*>’`

I've also considered adding a partial specialization for the whole class for pointer types which defines an extra member overloading `foo` that takes in a `const T*`, but I couldn't figure out how to reuse the rest of the code in the base template (i.e. without duplicating the declarations and definitions for all the other functions, e.g. `bar`). Is there a way to reference the base template class from the pointer partial specialization, either for inheritance or for having a member to which to forward calls? ([This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12923945/c-use-default-template-as-base-for-specialization) provides a solution by adding an extra dummy template argument. Is there a way to circumvent this?).

Finally, I've also thought about using `enable_if<is_pointer<T>::value, void>::type foo(const PointedToType*);` to add an extra overload to the `foo` method when the template parameter is a pointer, but how can one get `PointedToType` from `T` (when it is known that `T` is a pointer type)?

Comment: It's not clear to me what you need. Getting the call accepted could be as easy as turning `foo` into a template itself, i.e., `template<typename U> void foo(const U&){}` and adding some constrains with `static_assert` to the function's body - but I think it depends on the implementation of the *real* function whether or not that makes sense.

Comment: Unfortunately, the _real_ `A` is an interface which must be inherited from and C++ doesn't allow virtual template member functions.

Comment: Did you try `A<const int*> a:`?

Comment: `A` has a member variable of type `T` which must be non-const. Sorry for not specifying this in the question from the beginning.

Comment: @bbudescu Please add the info that `foo` is `virtual` to your question.  It made my answer useless.

Comment: @5gon12eder Sorry about that. Actually, your answer helped. I wasn't aware of `std::remove_pointer`. Declaring foo as `typename enable_if<is_pointer<T>::value, void>::type foo(const typename remove_pointer<T>::type *)` also does the trick.

Comment: I don't see how this can help here but if it does, I'll undelete my answer again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems to me that you just need a trait for what the argument type of `foo` should be:

```
template <typename T>
struct arg_type { using type = T const&; };

template <typename T>
struct arg_type<T*> { using type = T const*; };

template <typename T>
using arg_type_t = typename arg_type<T>::type;
```

To be used thusly:

```
virtual void foo(arg_type_t<T> arg ) {}
```

Comment: This does the trick quite nicely. However, do you think there would be a way to make the interface more legible (i.e. for an interface user to easily figure out what the method expects as a parameter)?

Comment: @bbudescu Add a comment?

Comment: I mean, if a user who is not very familiar with type traits sees the declaration `virtual void foo(arg_type_t<T> arg `, maybe he wouldn't be able to figure out that the function expects a `const T&` or  `const T*` right away. I was just wondering if there's a way to rewrite the code such that it is easier to deduce how to use it. Of course, comments would be very helpful in this situation. I'm not very familiar with type traits, and I was wondering whether there is a way to make the declaration more legible.

Comment: I added an edit to the question with what I ended up doing.

Comment: @bbudescu That's irrelevant to the question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/83371/discussion-between-bbudescu-and-barry).

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is what you want but you could use a combination of `std::is_pointer`, `std::remove_pointer` and `std::conditional` to construct the argument type you want.  I don't know how you would write the function body to do useful things with that argument, however.

```
#include <type_traits>

template <typename T>
struct A
{
  template <
    typename U = T,
    typename ArgT = std::conditional_t<
      std::is_pointer<U>::value,
      const std::remove_pointer_t<U> *,
      U>
  >
  void
  foo(const ArgT&)
  {
    // ...
  }
};
```

I'm using the C++14 type meta-functions here.  If you cannot use C++14, replace `std::fancy_t< … >` with `typename std::fancy< … >::type`.

The following is now valid:

```
int
main()
{
  {
    A<int *> a {};
    const int * p {};
    a.foo(p);
  }
  {
    A<int> a {};
    const int i {};
    a.foo(i);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just define `a` with a `const` template argument, i.e., `A<const int*> a;`. That would work.

```
template<typename T> class A{
public:
    void foo(const T &v){ m = v; }
    void bar(T &v){ v = m; }
    T m;
    // ... other member functions/variables ...
};

int main(){
    A<const int*> a;
    const int* p = nullptr;
    a.foo(p);
    a.bar(p);
}
```

Comment: Sorry I didn't specify this in the question from the beginning (I added a later edit to illustrate this). `A` has other members of type `T` which must be accessible by non-const references.

Comment: @bbudescu That still works. Notice the `bar()` member. It is expecting a non-`const` reference.

Comment: The functions behave like a setter / getter pair. The interface for the setter _should_ accept a `const` parameter, even if the data is not `const`.